# Reliable network reconnect loop in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets

I'm creating a client application that is supposed to maintain contact with my server. It's critical that this connection doens't drop, and if it does it should always reconnect eventually. This is pretty critical, so that customers don't sit there for hours wondering why nothing is going on.

This is the code i came up with:

```
Sub Connect()

    //These are actually globals
    Dim client As TcpClient
    Dim lastpacketreceived As DateTime = New DateTime(1, 1, 1)

    While 1
        Try

            If IsNothing(client) Then
                client = New TcpClient(host, port)
                Send("Connect|<credentials>")
                lastpacketreceived = DateTime.Now
                client.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf Read, Nothing)
            ElseIf ((DateTime.Now - lastpacketreceived).TotalMinutes > 3 Or client.Connected = False) Then
                Try : client.Client.Close() : Catch : End Try
                Try : client.Close() : Catch : End Try
                client = Nothing
            Else
                //Heartbeat. Receives "pong" from the server that updates the lastpacketreceived timeout counter.
                Send("Ping|") 
            End If

        Catch
        End Try

        Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)

    End While
End Sub
```

The idea here i hope is very clear. Loop every 10 seconds checking if the client object exists, check if there has been heartbeat in the last 3 minutes, or if everything is fine, just ping to reset the lastpacketreceived timeout counter.

The loop is shielded with a universal Try/Catch, and data received is handled asynchronously in a different thread (AddressOf Read), so if that crashes this loop should keep going.

So what's the problem with all this? I just had a customer call me telling me it's been running for hours and nothing has happened. On my end it connected once for a few minutes and then dissapeared and the connection still isn't back.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why not send keep alive objects back and forth two and from the server. Basically, send a small data packet, like just a few bytes, something your server then in turn can identify as a keepalive, and then have the server respond those packets with a similar packets, doing this every 30-60 seconds

Comment: I think I'm doing exactly that with my Send("Ping|"). It sends a ping to the server who then replies with a "Pong". When my client receives any data from the server, it updates the lastpacketreceived time to the current time.

Comment: *"nothing has happened"* is not a valid error message. Please post the real error message.

Comment: There is no real error message, the production client does not display error messageboxes to the customer. The customer just has a form up with a looping progress bar. That's it.

On my end i see that the client connected for about 5 minutes, and then disconnected, and hasn't returned.

The client does have an internet detection thread, which will display a messagebox if the client's box loses internet connectivity. It hasn't.

For the most part, I'm just interested in someone point out some obvious bug in what I'm doing, because I'm not very confident in it and I'm having these problems.

Comment: How do you know that there's no error? You swallow the exceptions without even logging them. I would say *that* is your "bug". You need to learn how to handle exceptions properly.

Comment: I didn't say there is no error. I said there is no error message. Even if i logged every exception, it wouldn't give me an answer about why the loop stopped, because the loop should continue after the exception is handled anyway. Not that it matters, because i have no access to any created logs anyway.

The whole point of this question is to ask what kind of exception or bug could occur in this code that would stop this loop from continuing forever. That's the question. Not "how do i log exceptions" or "how do i hook up a debugger and walk step by step until i find the problem".

Answer (score 1):

There is a better pattern

- Loop until connected.
- setup your receive loop - also test for *ZERO bytes received*, this also means you are disconnect
- have an independent send method
- have you periodic timer code in a separate loop that checks for connectivity repeatedly on an interval.

Here is some live code i use. You can add the rest as required but this should get you started:

```
#Region "Variables"
    Public Event Disconneted()

    Const BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 64
    Const TIMEOUT = 4000

    Private soc As Socket
    Private ep As EndPoint
    Private loggedin As Boolean
    Private are As New AutoResetEvent(False)
#End Region

Public Sub Connect()
    If IsConnected() = True Then
        Log("Already Connected")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    soc = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp) With {.SendBufferSize = BUFFER_SIZE}

    Try
        ep = GetIPEndPointFromHostName("149.154.167.40", 443)

        Dim arg = New SocketAsyncEventArgs With {.RemoteEndPoint = ep}
        AddHandler arg.Completed, AddressOf IO_Handler

        If Not soc.ConnectAsync(arg) Then
            IO_Handler(soc, arg)
        End If

        are.WaitOne(5000)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Log("Connect: " & ex.ToString, ConsoleColor.Red, True)
    End Try

    ReadData()
End Sub

Private Sub SendData(b() As Byte, Optional read As Boolean = False)
    If Not IsConnected() Then
        Log("Connection Closed!", ConsoleColor.DarkRed)
        RaiseEvent Disconneted()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim arg = New SocketAsyncEventArgs With {.RemoteEndPoint = ep}
    AddHandler arg.Completed, AddressOf IO_Handler
    arg.SetBuffer(b, 0, b.Length)

    Try
        If Not soc.SendAsync(arg) Then
            IO_Handler(soc, arg)
        End If

        If read Then
            ReadData()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Log("SendData: " & ex.ToString, ConsoleColor.Red)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub IO_Handler(sender As Object, e As SocketAsyncEventArgs)
    Log($"{e.LastOperation}:{e.SocketError}:{e.BytesTransferred}", ConsoleColor.Cyan)

    Select Case e.SocketError
        Case SocketError.Success
            Select Case e.LastOperation
                Case SocketAsyncOperation.Connect
                    Log("Connected to " & e.ConnectSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString, ConsoleColor.Green)
                    are.Set()
                Case SocketAsyncOperation.Disconnect, SocketAsyncOperation.Connect
                    RaiseEvent Disconneted()
                Case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive
                    HandleData(e)
            End Select
        Case SocketError.ConnectionAborted
            RaiseEvent Disconneted()
    End Select
End Sub

Private Function IsConnected() As Boolean
    Dim ret = False

    Try
        If soc IsNot Nothing Then
            ret = Not (soc.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) And soc.Available = 0)

            If ret = False Then
                loggedin = False
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        loggedin = False
    End Try

    Return ret
End Function

Private Function GetIPEndPointFromHostName(hostName As String, port As Integer) As IPEndPoint
    Dim addresses = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName)
    If addresses.Length = 0 Then
        Log("Unable to retrieve address from specified host name:  " & hostName, ConsoleColor.Red)
        Return Nothing
    End If
    Return New IPEndPoint(addresses(0), port)
End Function
```